# Shiny Document (HTML) Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am trying to create a Shiny Document (R Markdown).

I want to plot a basic scatterplot using ggplot2, with the possibility of selecting a variable related to the features to plot (i.e. in this case I will plot radiance over the time, and the user will be able to select the village which the radiance refers).

```
inputPanel(
  selectInput("v", label = "Village:",
              choices = villages$village, selected = "Voas")
)

renderPlot({
ggplot(input$v, aes(x=date, y=radiance)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method=lm, formula = y ~ x)
})
```

And when I "Run Document" I got this error:

> Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
>    Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 5, >column 6
>   Calls:  ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load ->

My YAML header looks like this (I haven´t changed anything in it):

```
---
title: "Problem-Shiny"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit unclear as to why you end up with an error involving `yaml::yaml.load` but I think the main issue seems to be with you not using `ggplot` correctly. The first (`data`) argument of `ggplot` is the `data.frame` to be used for plotting. In your code, you instead provide a scalar (`input$v`).

Since you don't provide reproducible sample data, here's a minimal reproducible example based on the `mtcars` dataset.

First the RMarkdown document with `shiny` backend

````
---
title: "Problem-Shiny"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
inputPanel(
  selectInput("carb", label = "Carburetors:",
              choices = sort(mtcars$carb))
)

renderPlot({
ggplot(mtcars[mtcars$carb == input$carb, ], aes(mpg, disp)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method=lm, formula = y ~ x)
})
```
````

This produces the following `shiny`-backed HTML document

[image]

---

As an alternative you may want to use a `reactive` data structure that returns a filtered (based on the input of `selectInput`) `data.frame`. This has the advantage that you can use the filtered `data()` in other places as well (not just for plotting).

````
---
title: "Problem-Shiny"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
inputPanel(
    selectInput(
        "carb", 
        label = "Carburetors:",
        choices = sort(mtcars$carb))
)

data <- reactive({ 
    mtcars[mtcars$carb == input$carb, ]
})

renderPlot({
    ggplot(data(), aes(mpg, disp)) + 
        geom_point() +
        geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x)
})
```
````

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mauritus. You are right, I forgot to filter the dataframe in ggplot, but is because I didn´t get there :) I still get this error at the beginning in YAML. I have seen some comments elsewhere about reseting internal YAML code, but not sure if my case is because the code. Btw, I don´t know how can I upload sample code to this post. If you tell me I will post it, but it is a very simple dataframe (village [char], date[date], radiance[float]).

Comment: @natxoreguera It is difficult to help without a fully reproducible code example. If you copy&paste the example I give (based on `mtcars`) and then click "Run Document" in RStudio it will (and should) compile just fine. Can you verify that this is the case for you? Once you've verified that the example works, you should try to understand what's different in your code from the example code I give. If it doesn't compile the issue may be with your RStudio setup.

Comment: I understand, I did followed your directions and it worked! Thanks! Btw, the problem with shiny was that I had another Rdm files in the same folder, so I don´t know why YAML read those other YAML codes in the Rdm files. I just moved them to another folder and it rendered fine.